# How to place the vertex name into vertex?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I want to look the local-disk-directory structrue use this code.

```
g = NestGraph[
   Select[FileNames["*", #], DirectoryQ] &, $InstallationDirectory, 2,
    GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left, 
     "LeafDistance" -> .1}];
SetProperty[g, 
 VertexLabels -> Table[a -> FileNameTake[a], {a, VertexList[g]}]]
```

[image]

But I have some dissatisfaction with it.I want to put vertex name into vertex like this:

[image]

But I cannot use `Placed[FileNameTake["Name"], Center]`.Any solution can do this?

Comment: Try `VertexLabels ->  Table[a -> Placed[FileNameTake[a], Center], {a, VertexList[g]}]]`

Comment: @Szabolcs Done.Thanks.`panelLabel[lbl_]:=Panel[lbl,FrameMargins->0,Background->Lighter[Yellow,0.7]];g=NestGraph[Select[FileNames["*",#],DirectoryQ]&,$InstallationDirectory,2];UndirectedGraph[g,GraphLayout->{"LayeredEmbedding","Orientation"->Left,"LeafDistance"->.1},VertexLabels->Table[a->Placed[FileNameTake[a],Center,panelLabel],{a,VertexList[g]}]]`

Comment: Please post your comment as an answer because it is an answer, and also it is unreadable in present form.

Comment: @QuantumDot Thanks for your advice.

Comment: @rhermans You are editting thost post one by one or you find a automatical method?

Comment: Automated, but now I notice it has many bugs.

Answer (score 3):

Per suggestion,I post my comment as answer for reading to show your local-disk-directory structrue.If it is a directory,I will show it with yellow.

```
panelLabel[lbl_] := 
  Framed[FileNameTake[lbl], FrameMargins -> 1, FrameStyle -> None, 
   RoundingRadius -> 3, 
   Background -> Lighter[If[DirectoryQ[lbl], Yellow, Red], 0.5]];
g = NestGraph[FileNames["*", #] &, $InstallationDirectory, 2];
UndirectedGraph[g, 
 GraphLayout -> {"LayeredEmbedding", "Orientation" -> Left, 
   "LeafDistance" -> .1}, 
 VertexLabels -> 
  Table[a -> Placed[a, Left, panelLabel], {a, VertexList[g]}], 
 VertexSize -> 0]
```

http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-10-05-15-38-14.png

Comment: Great.  You can also use `VertexShapeFunction`, `VertexShapeFunction -> (Text[panelLabel[#2], #1 - {.02, 0}, Left] &), VertexStyle -> Black`

Comment: @halmir Thanks :)